# Alternative to sscanf_s in C++

Tags: c++, regex, scanf

```
result = sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "data (%d,%d)", &a, &b);
```

In the code above I am using *sscanf_s* to extract two integer values from the given string *line*. Is there another way, more object-oriented, of doing that in C++11? (std::stringstream and/or regular expressions?)

EDIT: I tried two solutions, first one doesn't work, second one does

```
// solution one (doesn't work)
// let line = "data (3,4)"
std::regex re("data (.*,.*)");
std::smatch m;

if (std::regex_search(line, m, re) )
   cout << m[0] << " "<< m[1]; // I get the string "data (3,4) (3,4)"

// solution two (works but is somewhat ugly)
std::string name;
char openParenthesis;
char comma;
char closeParenthesis;
int x = 0, y = 0;

std::istringstream stream(line);
stream >> name >> openParenthesis >> a >> comma >> b >> closeParenthesis;

if( name=="data" && openParenthesis == '(' && comma == ',' && closeParenthesis == ')' )
{ 
    a = x;
    b = y;
}
```

EDIT 2: With Shawn's input, the following works perfectly:

```
    std::regex re(R"(data \(\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\))");
    std::smatch m;

    if (std::regex_search(line, m, re) )
    {
        a = std::stoi(m[1]);
        b = std::stoi(m[2]);
    }
```

Comment: There's always alternatives. The important question here is why you need something better, as "better" is usually moving in a particular direction.

Comment: By "better", I meant more object-oriented.

Comment: You'll need to convert that to using C++ streams, something that's not always straightforward. `scanf` is unusually flexible.

Comment: You could declare a data type for `data`, then implement a method to input the members from an `std::istream`.  That may be more *object-oriented", but may not be *better*.

Comment: `std::regex re("data (.*,.*)");
std::smatch m;

if (std::regex_search(line, m, re) )
 cout << m[0] << " "<< m[1];`

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble formatting the code I posted above. I am trying my hand at regular expressions but I get the wrong result. I thought that std::smatch would contain a list of the integers I parsed from the string.

Comment: Would just like to point out that C++ is technically multiparadigm; you don’t have to use objects _all_ of the time.

Comment: Parenthesis are special metacharacters in regular expressions... you want something more like `R"(data \(\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\))"` to get a RE equivalent to that scanf pattern.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. That works. Could you put your solution in the form of an answer so I can accept it as the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

If it has not to be regex *per se*, you could use [Boost.Spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/). The following is a slight modification of [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/number_list___stuffing_numbers_into_a_std__vector.html) and gives you any number of comma-separated integers in a vector. (That is not exactly what you requested, but showing off a bit of what else would be possible, and also I didn't want to put more effort into changing the example).

This works on iterators, i.e. strings as well as streams. It's also trivially expandable to more complex grammars, and you can create stand-alone grammar *objects* you can re-use, or combine into yet more complex grammars. (Not demonstrated here.)

```
#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

template < typename Iterator >
bool parse_data( Iterator first, Iterator last, std::vector< int > & v )
{
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse( first, last,
                // Begin grammar
                (
                        qi::lit( "data" ) >> '('
                        >> qi::int_[ phoenix::push_back( phoenix::ref( v ), qi::_1 ) ]
                        >> *( ',' >> qi::int_[ phoenix::push_back( phoenix::ref( v ), qi::_1 ) ] )
                        >> ')'
                ),
                // End grammar
                ascii::space );

        if ( first != last ) // fail if we did not get a full match
        {
                return false;
        }

        return r;
}

int main()
{
        std::string input = "data (38,4)";
        std::vector< int > v;
        if ( parse_data( input.begin(), input.end(), v ) )
        {
                std::cout << "Read:\n";
                for ( auto i : v )
                {
                        std::cout << i << "\n";
                }
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "Failed.\n";
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input DevSolar. It looks good but I should have mentioned that I can't use Boost.

Comment: @melanie93: That's a limitation I always raise one and a half eyebrows at, unless for educational purposes in the classroom. Boost is the second most "standard" library after `std::` itself.

Comment: You are right in that this is for educational purposes. I am not sure why we were instructed not to use Boost but I assumed it might be because it is harder to learn for beginners. I went with std::regex instead of sscanf because I wanted to use something more "modern".